# Is there a way changes to a variable is permanent?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am working on some sort of Online Lesson Calendar. I have figured a way to get the user's input and display on the calendar. However, when I restart the code either on my device or on the host, it does not save the changes I have made onto the variable beforehand. Is there a way to make these changes save? If you have any more questions needed to answer this query, just comment below!

Comment: According to what you are saying I think it makes more sense to use some sort of a database on your application.  You can choose from a wide variety of them NoSql(MongoDb), Relational(MySql, Postgress, SQL). the data dont just gets saved without a database

Comment: do you know any good guides for a database?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest learning the very basics of MySQL, here is the link for a youtube video [moshHamedani](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S_tz1z_5bA&t=1525s) OR you can download a book called MySQL notes for professionals, here [MySQLNotesForProfessional](https://books.goalkicker.com/MySQLBook/). Bare in mind that in order to use a database you will need a knowladge of serversite scripting. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an npm install that allows a bot to save settings and import them every time the bot starts up. There are many guides online and if you already know SQL its a breeze to get going.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3

Here is the npm install site. Please update us on your progress.

Comment: I do not know if I am doing this right as I am a newbie but when I try and install in my discord bot file directory a bunch of errors occur and says at the end:
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.

Comment: Try installing sqlite instead, it is slower than sqlite3, but it is not noticeable https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite

Comment: i have successfully installed sqlite3, i have been looking with guides from online, but I cannot see one dedicated to discord.js. Some of the guides mention SQLite tools, do I have to install these? For your information, I am currently using DB Browser. Thanks for the help

Comment: where you installed the module, there is documentation below. Don't expect to understand it immediately, it does take time since it is like learning another (very very simple) programming language

Answer (score -1):

you can use [local storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage) to save variables locally 
install with `npm i node-localstorage`

```js
if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) {
  var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
  localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
}
 
localStorage.setItem('myFirstKey', 'myFirstValue');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('myFirstKey'));
```